# How to remove standard output from vstest.console test run?

Tags: c#, c, unit-testing, vstest

When I run the below code in the Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio:

```
vstest.console.exe UnitTestAssemblyName.dll
```

I receive the following:

```
Passed   Test_1   
Text
Text
Text
(...)
Passed   Test_2
```

Where "Text" is logged as a result of Test_2 C# unit test that uses a C library with a fprintf(stdout, "Text") statement. I want to remove these "Text" output lines, so that they do not appear in the console log, but I cannot change that C library. Is there any way this could be achieved?

I am aware of a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35125183/removing-standard-output-messages-from-console-window), which has an approved answer that recommends using MSTest instead of VSTest in this instance. However, it is not a good solution in my case, because I am moving from MSTest to VSTest and that is why I have started seeing this issue.

Comment: So essentially the managed unit test assembly is using P/Invoke to call 'C' functions in an unmanaged DLL, and those 'C' functions are using `fprintf()` to produce diagnostic output that is unwanted in the unit test log?

Comment: Yes @MatthewWatson that is correct.